# differents between web3.eth.signTransaction And web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction

Tags: web3js, transactions

I don't understand the differents between these methods

[web3.eth.signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#signtransaction)
and
[web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=signTransaction#signtransaction)

And when I have to use.
If I try to use `web3.eth.signTransaction` with ganache or infura I get this error

Method eth_signTransaction not supported / The method eth_signTransaction does not exist/is not available

Answer (score 0):

the function parameters are what differentiates them for the first one(web3.eth.signTransaction), you have to pass the private key of the account you want to use, while for the other(web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction) you have to ensure the account is unlocked before you call it

Comment: Thanks, But when I have to use eth.sign insted accounts.sign ? And Why I get that error ? thanks

Comment: unfortunately i don't have enough information to tell you why that happens you should maybe paste your code.

Comment: the same of documentation

Comment: it should be "signTransaction" and not "eth_signTransaction" you should remove the  underscore between eth and signTransaction